# Will updating the assemblies File Version have any impact on a BizTalk application?

Tags: versioning, biztalk, biztalk-2010

Will updating the assemblies file version have any impact on a BizTalk application?

I want a simple approach to versioning the various assemblies in a BizTalk application, as we'd had a couple of occasions where for external reasons, we weren't sure the right "version" had been deployed ...

They're all currently just 1.0.0.0 ...

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

We're not looking at side-by-side deployments, anything flashy, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**

Changing the `AssemblyFileVersion` will have no effect on the application, only changing the `AssemblyVersion` will. In fact at my company we change the `AssemblyFileVersion` as a standard, this way you can tell what version is deployed in an environment.